# Supply PHP function ssh2_auth_pubkey_file with private key as string, not a file

Tags: php

I am trying to pass a string containing content of a RSA private key file to a PHP function [ssh2_auth_pubkey_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-auth-pubkey-file.php):

My function looks like this: `ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($connection, $ssh_auth_user, $ssh_auth_pub, $ssh_auth_priv, $ssh_auth_pass)`

My problem is `string $pubkeyfile` in my function it is `$ssh_auth_priv` parameter. Everything works fine when I supply it with a pointer to file for example `'private.pem'` but when I pass content of the file as string, I get error.

- `$ssh_auth_priv = 'private.pem';` works

I have tried:

- `$ssh_auth_priv = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
  MIIEpQIBAAKCAQEA6Gfo+vYawTT6afHSxBeMYx/s/5nsMHmdckTUj5wPNdG2LhPX
  ywGGzyRB9qFAIJAaGmT9fPcgt/IIySOOqzvLGPXbdk15HW71FC8nVQmBYrQXWQnB
  ........
  i3pcqQ2JwSgi9M6rVxDSHQrVVBhiXvAx7Q2B/TEf1BvhtxXdSntUUu63U13VGiOF
  1J5RW3EjAeamKOEpaL75xQSSFZdqc7KUG6+cqejhyNkZ4oDk7x+gjuU=
  -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
  ";` does not work
- `$ssh_auth_priv = <<<KEY-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
  MIIEpQIBAAKCAQEA6Gfo+vYawTT6afHSxBeMYx/s/5nsMHmdckTUj5wPNdG2LhPX
  ywGGzyRB9qFAIJAaGmT9fPcgt/IIySOOqzvLGPXbdk15HW71FC8nVQmBYrQXWQnB
  ........
  i3pcqQ2JwSgi9M6rVxDSHQrVVBhiXvAx7Q2B/TEf1BvhtxXdSntUUu63U13VGiOF
  1J5RW3EjAeamKOEpaL75xQSSFZdqc7KUG6+cqejhyNkZ4oDk7x+gjuU=
  -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
  KEY;` Heredoc does not work
- I tried `file_get_contents` to a string, did not work.

My question is how to pass public key as a string, not a pointer to a file.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to write the private key to a temp file and provide the name of that temp file to `ssh2_auth_pubkey_file()`, eg:

```
$session = ssh2_connect($host, $port, ['hostkey' => 'ssh-rsa']);
$tempPrivateKeyFileName = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'id_rsa');
$fp = fopen($tempPrivateKeyFileName, 'wb+');
fwrite($fp, $yourPrivateKeyContents);
ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($session, $username, $pubkeyfile, $tempPrivateKeyFileName, $passphrase);
unlink($tempPrivateKeyFileName);
```

It's worth noting writing the private key to a file where it may be read by other processes may be risky depending on your application and environment. At the least you probably want to ensure the private key is encrypted with a passphrase. You may also wish to add a shutdown handler to ensure the temp file is removed if the process exits abnormally. eg:

```
register_shutdown_function(static function () use ($tempPrivateKeyFileName) {
    if (file_exists($tempPrivateKeyFileName)) {
        unlink($tempPrivateKeyFileName);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a string for the public key filename argument, it has to be a filename. The function is defined that way.